# How can i navigate to next page on clicking the radio button in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, onclick

```
  InkWell(
                            onTap: () async {
                              proselect = await Navigator.push(context,
                                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                                return info();
                              }));
                            },
                            child: addRadioButton(0, "Job Seeker"),
                          ),
```

By doing this, by clicking on the text it is navigating to the next page but on clicking on the radio button it doesn't work.

And this is the code of radio button function

```
Row addRadioButton(int btnValue, String title) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        Radio(
          activeColor: Colors.black,
          value: position[btnValue],
          groupValue: select,
          onChanged: (value) {
            onTap:
            {
              setState(() {
                print(value);
                select = value;
              });
            }
            ;
          },
        ),
        Text(title, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
      ],
    );
```

Answer (score 2):

The `onTap` is not going to work, for the simple fact that it's not a property of the *Radio* widget. Instead, you can create a bool and set it to true whenever it is tapped, then check with a condition and navigate to a different page.

```
bool navigateToPage = false;

 onChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  navigateToPage = true;
                });
                
                if (navigateToPage) {
                  Navigator.push(context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                    return info();
                  }));
                }
              }
```

Answer (score 1):

one of the basic way according to your implementation would be to update the onTap function for Radio like this:

```
Row addRadioButton(int btnValue, String title) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        Radio(
          activeColor: Colors.black,
          value: position[btnValue],
          groupValue: select,
          onChanged: (value) {
            onTap:
            {
              setState(() {
                print(value);
                select = value;
              });
              proselect = await Navigator.push(context,
                                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                                return info();
                              }));
            }
            ;
          },
        ),
        Text(title, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
      ],
    );
```